Plesk Server: SSH works, but SFTP doesn´t (with FileZilla and PHPStorm)
First some info about my system/server:

Plesk Obsidian v18.0.64_build1800241008.13 os_Ubuntu 24.04
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Hosted by IONOS
Setup is one subscription with one main Domain. There are multiple
subdomains with different pages.

What is the problem?
The problem is, that the SFTP user isn´t working on external Tools like PHPStorm or Filezilla. SSH itself is working (I use Putty and the Backen Plesk Terminal). When I first log into SSH and then log into SFTP via console "sftp user@host" it´s suddenly working. But as soon as I try to connect to SFTP via FileZilla or PHPStorm I get errors. Just to mention, FTP is also not working (Just the same situation as with SFTP).
UPDATE: When I access from a different IP Address it´s suddenly working for me from FileZilla (PHPStorm still doesn´t work), but my colleague still can´t access it.
UPDATE 2: The SPECIFIC problem IS that SFTP and FTP don´t work on a Plesk Server when connecting with Tools like PHPStorm or FileZilla.
I don´t get any errors or warnings, except the ones listed below.
I rechecked, tested, and tried solutions, but I am stuck and came to the forum.
If you think I should ask somewhere else please say so.
Or if you have any further ideas of configurations, settings, or things I could try please say so.
I provided everything I know and have about the problem.
UPDATE 3: It now works for the main user (No clue why, since no one did anything else than described on this post), but not for any other SFTP users (For these users the only setting I can influence while creating them via Plesk backend is their access, name and password. So I can´t set their SSH access this way.).
What errors do I get when connecting?

EOT while reading packet
Session timed out
Session closed
Stream closed

What ideas do I have for a cause?

I thought it could maybe be a permission problem or a configuration
problem
Maybe it has something to do with allowed IPs
Maybe external access is blocked or limited for some reason?

What have I tried?

I checked the Ports. But both 21 and 22 are enabled.
I checked the firewall. The firewall is enabled. But both Ports (22 and
21) are allowed. Also, external Traffic is allowed
I checked the SSH config, but SFTP was enabled.
I tried using the Plesk check and repair tool. But everything was
fine.
I checked the logs, but they only say "The session was
closed".No error or warning.
I tried creating a new SFTP user, but the problem persisted.
Set SSh access from "Forbidden" to "/bin/sh"
Rechecked credentials
Update: It suddenly works now on my FileZilla. But it´s not IP-related since my colleague from the same IP still encounters the issue in Filezilla
Update: Tried emptying the cache

What did I expect?
Well, I expected SFTP to work from FileZilla and PHPStorm.
I would be glad to have any ideas. Or maybe some of you already encountered the issue?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
